# Castle Windsor multiple implementations of interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have the following installer but for some odd reason it is not resolving correctly. I have an interface where there are 2 implementations of it but want to inject the correct instance based on `naming conventions`.

I am expecting in this instance that the correct instance of `ICommand` will be injected based on how they are named. However, for some odd reason both controllers are picking the very first instance, i.e. `FooCommand` due to it being defined first in the installer.

Not sure what I have done wrong? Perhaps, is there an alternative way of doing this?

```
public interface ICommand { }

public class FooCommand : ICommand { }

public class BarCommand : ICommand { }

public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    public SomeController(ICommand fooCommand) { }
}

public class HelloController : ApiController
{
    public HelloController(ICommand barCommand) { }
}

container.Register(
    Component.For<ICommand>()
        .Named("fooCommand")
        .ImplementedBy<FooCommand>()
        .LifestyleSingleton(),
    Component.For<ICommand>()
        .Named("barCommand")
        .ImplementedBy<BarCommand>()
        .LifestyleSingleton());
```

Comment: So you want to inject a `FooCommand` in `SomeController` and `BarCommand` in `HelloController`? But what happens to those controllers if you swap the dependencies, i.e. inject `BarCommand` into `SomeController`? Does this break `SomeController` or will it continue to function correctly?

Comment: It will break it as they both will end up talking to different underlying tables.

Comment: In that case you are violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and that's the root of your problem. To solve this, give both commands their own unique interface.

Comment: You also might want to take a look at using a more message driven design, such as [this one](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91).

Comment: In your real code, what does FooCommand and BarCommand do?

Comment: Real world it simply executes a SQL command to some table. @Steven I don't really agree with your approach as that would mean I would have two interfaces that are identical. This is simply a different implementation. Your approach would mean having an interface per concrete implementation.

Comment: I have figured out a way of doing this and that is NOT to use the naming convention but have an installer on a per controller basis injecting the correct implementation.

Comment: How are you using the container? By creating an implementation of IHttpControllerActivator?

Comment: @YacoubMassad yes using that approach. Are you are thinking about using the Resolve() option?

Comment: I have not used Windsor before, but similar to Unity, I am guessing there should be a way to register your controllers with the container, and during registration you can tell Windsor which implementation of ICommand to use with which controller.

Comment: It doesn't really matter that the interfaces look the same; what's important is their contract and their behavior is different. They behave differently and are therefore contractually different. This means that they need both a different interface; The [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles don't lie.

Comment: @Steven you make a valid point perhaps I try not to be an absolute purest about SOLID as sometimes it over complicates matters rather than solving them. However I do agree with you and perhaps I can break out the interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @steven said, it's generally not a good idea and if not managed properly may lead to discoverability issues down the line, but assuming you know what you're doing you can build a `IContributeComponentModelConstruction` that will match constructor parameters of type `ICommand` on your controllers with Windsor components having the same name.

```
public class ControllerCommandMatcher : IContributeComponentModelConstruction
{
    public void ProcessModel(IKernel kernel, ComponentModel model)
    {
        // or whatever other condition to bail out quickly
        if (model.Implementation.Name.EndsWith("Controller") == false) return;

        foreach (var constructor in model.Constructors)
        {
            foreach (var dependency in constructor.Dependencies)
            {
                if (dependency.TargetItemType != typeof (ICommand)) continue;
                dependency.Parameter = new ParameterModel(dependency.DependencyKey,
                    ReferenceExpressionUtil.BuildReference(dependency.DependencyKey));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The tricky bit is this:

```
new ParameterModel(dependency.DependencyKey,
       ReferenceExpressionUtil.BuildReference(dependency.DependencyKey))
```

It basically tells Windsor that the dependency (the constructor parameter), for example `fooCommand` should be satisfied with a component of the same name (`fooCommand`).

Then add your contributor to the container

```
container.Kernel.ComponentModelBuilder.AddContributor(new ControllerCommandMatcher());
```

[Here's the documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/componentmodel-construction-contributors.md)

Comment: I'll give this a whirl and feedback thanks for the post. Though I don't understand the last 2 lines of code what do they do? How does it know which instance to inject in?